# Where is property in Number object?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = new Number(4);
```

I have created object with 4 as argument to a constructor.

1. Is 4 a property of that object? Does it have a name/key, like 0 : 4?
2. Why I can not iterate over that object (preform *for in* loop)?

I ask this because when I log `a` all I get is this seemingly pointless picture. It does not tell me much about object.

[image]

Comment: Did you at all try to find the answer for yourself? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: @Derek Yes, what about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `Number` object, the value you passed is assigned to the `slot` for that object.  You really can't access it like you do a property, but if you expand the object as shown below, you can see the slot, which is denoted by `[[PrimitiveValue]]`.  You can treat this object just like a regular number, and perform operations like addition, subtraction, etc. (see screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the console in the browser you can find a property with name `[[PrimitiveValue]]` which contains the value of the Number. The value of that object is retrieved via `valueOf` function

Google Chrome

[image]

Comment: Ahh, the good old Chrome. I forgot that its console is superior to Firefoxes.